# How do I get protractor to check for an element before the page loads completely?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am starting off on a non-angular page, clicking a button with browser.findElement.

Upon clicking on the element the user is taken to an angular page that has a spinner until the page load is complete. Using the following code, protractor waits for the page to load completely before doing the below and I would like it to begin checking for the page-busy-indicator as soon as the initial button is clicked because by the time it gets to this code, the spinner is no longer active.

```
browser.wait(function(){
  element(by.className('page-busy-indicator')).getAttribute('class').then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
    if(value.indexOf('active')>-1){
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` before the `browser.wait()`?

Comment: I have tried ignoreSynchronization and waitForAngularEnabled all over the place to no avail.

Comment: `var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf($('.page-busy-indicator')), 5000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to finspin and Barney for their comments that pointed me in the right direction.  In the end, I needed to turn off waitForAngularEnabled and then use the opposite of what Barney had mentioned (presenceOf). Sorry if the question was confusing because of the way I worded it. Thanks again!

Note that what this is doing is setting up a watch for .page-busy-indicator.active and looking for it for 5 seconds before timing out.

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element(by.css('.page-busy-indicator.active'))), 5000);
```